# how to display Card image in full screen

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

i use this code to display cards in homepage.js component
i got the data in my cards good  but when i click on the image to get it with full screen i got same image every time

noimg is an image that when the array of images empty i display this

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleModalShow = () => setShowModal(true);
  const handleModalClose = () => setShowModal(false);
```

```
dataposts.map((d)=>{return <>
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
   <Card.Img variant="top" src={d.images[0]==null ? noimg : d.images[0].image} style={{marginLeft:10,marginTop:20, width: '15rem',height: '15rem' }} onClick={handleModalShow}/>
   <Card.Body>
     <Card.Title>{"name: " +d.name}</Card.Title>
   </Card.Body>
   <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
     <ListGroup.Item >{"number :"+ number}</ListGroup.Item>
     <ListGroup.Item>{"type:"+ type}</ListGroup.Item>
   </ListGroup>
   <Card.Body>
     <Link to={'Carddetails'} state={d.id} >
     <Button variant="primary" >details</Button>
     </Link>
     
     
   </Card.Body>
   <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleModalClose} size="lg">
        <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <img src={d.images[0]==null ? noimg : d.images[0].image} alt={lname} style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} />
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal> 
 </Card>
 
   </>

 })
```

Comment: What library are you using? This does not really look like the modal from [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal)

Comment: yes its from react-modal ```import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'```

Comment: That's from **bootstrap** which is a different package